# Sort directory files by number

Tags: bash, osx, ls

I have this directory

```
$ ls
0    2    4    config.yml
1    3    catalog.svg
```

The subdirectories are numbered starting from 0. I need to get the maximum number.

When trying `ls | sort -n` I get

```
0
catalogIcon-gitlab.svg
config.yml
1
2
3
4
```

What's happening here? Why is c between 0 and 1?

How do I write my command to get the top number?

System: bash, MacOS

Comment: zsh available? `zsh -c 'print *(/n[-1])'`

Comment: "c" shows up after "0" because the **numeric** values of those filenames is zero.

Comment: Related: [What does sort -n do with non numeric values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165060/what-does-sort-n-do-with-non-numeric-values)

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, zsh prints `config.yml` with `zsh -c 'print *(/n[-1])'`

Comment: @Isaac I assumed that the svg and yml filenames represented *files*, not *directories*, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Question: what exactly do you mean by "top number"? 0? or 4? Highest number or lowest number? You said "maximum" earlier, so I assume you want the directory with the highest number? Others have answered why sort places the files between 0 and 1. Are you only trying to return the highest numbered directory, and nothing else?

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get the max numbered directory:

```
max=$(printf "%s\n" */ | sort -n | tail -1)
echo "${max%/}"
```

Comment: ls | sort -n | tail -n 1

Answer (score 2):

`sort -n` sorts "according to string numerical value"; in this situation, when `sort` tries to numerically compare a number to a letter, it falls back to `memcmp` of the corresponding bytes, putting `c` (ASCII 99) after `0` (ASCII 48). With GNU sort's `--debug` option, you can see the failure happening:

```
$ ls |sort -n --debug
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
0
_
_
catalogIcon-gitlab.svg
^ no match for key
______________________
zoo
^ no match for key
___
1
# ... continues ...
```

For a bash-only solution, I would use a loop (assuming, as you indicate, that directories start from `0`):

```
highest=-1
for d in *; do [[ -d "$d" ]] || continue; [[ "$d" -gt "$highest" ]] && highest=$d; done
printf '%s\n' "$highest"
```

Comment: wow, the bash-only solution is quite long. is there no shorter one?

Comment: [glenn has a decent one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471670/117549)

Answer (score 0):

`ls` will already sort lexically by default.  You're just reading them in the wrong order when laid out in short form like that.  Read down each column and then to the next.  To see the actual lexical order `ls` is using, have it output one object per line:

```
$ ls -1
0
1
2
3
4
catalog.svg
config.yml
```

Comment: Note that with lexicographical ordering, 2 sorts after 12.

Comment: ok, but how to get the maximum filename of the subdirs?

Answer (score 0):

How about?:

```
ls -1v
0
1
2
3
4
12
23
catalog.svg
config.yml
```

v means `version` sort order.

To get the last (biggest) number, select only numbers:

```
$ ls -1v | grep -x '[0-9]*'
0
1
2
3
4
12
23
```

And tail it:

```
$ ls -1v | grep -x '[0-9]*' | tail -n 1
23
```

An only bash solution:

```
$ max=0; for d in */; do d=${d%/}; [[ d -gt max ]] && max=$d; done; printf '%d\n' "$max"
23
```